# Elaborating why the fundamental group of the circle is infinite cyclic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

The book of "Introduction to knot theory" of Richard H. Crowell, gives the following proof:

> [image]

where (5.7) is:

"Equivalent loops have equal winding numbers."

And (5.5) is:

$$r_{a.b} = r_{a} + r_{b}.$$

where $r_{a}$ is a uniquely determined integer, which we call the winding number of $a$. Geometrically, $r_{a}$ is the algebraic number of times the loop $a$ wraps around the circle.

And (5.6) is:

Loops with equal winding numbers are equivalent.

**My questions are:**

1-why (5.6) proves that the homomorphism is, in fact, an isomorphism ?

2-why there is no retraction from a space with trivial fundamental group to a subspace of an infinite cyclic fundamental group?

3-Intuitively what does it mean for a subspace to have infinite  cyclic fundamental group?

4-Why the definition of multiplication in the fundamental group and (5.5) show that this association is a homomorphism into the additive group of integers?

Could anyone help me in answering these questions please?

Comment: Two of the observations directly address surjectivity and injectivity without saying it explicitly. One observation is pretty explicitly saying why it is a homomorphism. For your second question you want to look at the induced maps coming from the retraction and the inclusion of the retract. For your third question, it just means that there is one hole in your space, intuitively.

Comment: 1) Clearly there are only countably many equivalence classes of loops so to show isomorphism it suffices that the homomorphism from equivalence classes of loops into the integers is injective. Statement $(5.6)$ says that if two loops map to the same integer (winding number) then they are equivalent (belong to the same equivalence class), which is just exactly what it means for the homomorphism to be injective. This is basically just your classic statement of injectivity, $\phi(a)=\phi(b) \implies a=b$, but phrased a little awkwardly in terms of equivalence classes.

Comment: 3) As Connor said, yeah, it's basically just that there's a hole in your space. All paths are either null-homotopic, or wind around the loop a finite number of times. A single winding generates the group.

4) The definition of a group homomorphism is that it preserves the structure of the group operation. In this case, our homomorphism $\phi: a \mapsto r_a$ takes us from a group with multiplication like $a\cdot b$ to a group with an addition operation like $r_a + r_b$, and we see that $\phi(a\cdot b) = r_{a\cdot b} = r_{a} + r_{b} = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$, as required.

Comment: I should have said in 1) that the fact that the homomorphism is surjective is obvious since you can arbitrarily wind a loop around any integer-valued number of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read Crowell's book, but I have read the proof in Massey's *Algebraic Topology*, which appears to be similar in flavor.  Let's start with an outline of the proof:

- Given a differentiable function $f:[0,1] \to S^1$ with $f(0)=f(1)=1\in S^1$, we can calculate the winding number $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_f d\theta$, where $d\theta$ measures changes in angle, measured in radians.  (This is where covering space theory might come in: there is no corresponding global parameterization $\theta$ of $S^1$, since if you go around the circle once it will have to have a discontinuity, a fact the fundamental group will measure.  The $\mathbb{R}$ cover of $S^1$ is a sort of "extended angle" approach, where the "extended angles" $2\pi k+s\in\mathbb{R}$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ all represent the same point of $S^1$.  There is a way to take a path like $f$ and "lift" it to a path $\widetilde{f}:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ through the "extended angles," and it turns out that $\frac{1}{2\pi}(\widetilde{f}(1)-\widetilde{f}(0))$ is the winding number!)
- Observe that winding numbers are $\mathbb{Z}$-valued.  We actually do not need differentiability of the path, using the following idea.  The circle can be written as the union of two open arcs $U,V\subset S^1$ whose intersection is a disjoint union of two smaller open arcs containing $1$ and $-1\in S^1$, respectively. (I am thinking of $S^1$ as being the complex unit circle.)  The preimages $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are disjoint unions of arcs.  By compactness of $[0,1]$, there is a finite collection of (relatively) open arcs $J_1,\dots, J_n\subseteq [0,1]$ with $\bigcup_iJ_i=[0,1]$ such that for all $i$ either $f(J_i)\subseteq U$ or $f(J_i)\subseteq V$.  This means there is a sequence $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=1$ such that $f([t_i,t_{i+1}])\subset U$ or $f([t_i,t_{i+1}])\subset V$ (or both) for all $i$.  We can arrange for $f(t_i)\in\{1,-1\}$ for all $i$ by homotoping $f$ to have small spurs, which is possible since each component of $U\cap V$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so straight-line homotopies exist.  Since $U$ and $V$ are both homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, we can homotope $f|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ so that it takes a shortest path for each $i$ from $f(t_i)$ to $f(t_{i+1})$.  If $f$ is stationary on any interval, we can homotope $f$ to remove that interval.  Thus, on each interval $f$ either makes a half turn clockwise or counterclockwise.  If $f$ ever changes directions, then there is some pair of intervals $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ and $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ where $f$ goes in opposite directions, and you can homotope $f$ so it remains stationary on $[t_{i-1},t_{i+1}]$.  Thus, we may eventually homotope $f$ so that it is monotonically clockwise or counterclockwise.  After one more homotopy, we can assume $t_i=i/n$ for each $i$. This implies $f$, in this form, can be parameterized by $f(t)=e^{2\pi i kt}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and we can call $k$ the winding number of the original $f$.
- This version of winding number is well-defined since homotopy is an equivalence relation.  If $f\sim g$, $f\sim e^{2\pi ikt}$, and $g\sim e^{2\pi i\ell t}$, then $e^{2\pi ikt}\sim e^{2\pi i\ell t}$.  The generalized Stokes theorem implies line integrals over homotopic loops are equal, so the integral-based winding number definition implies $k=\ell$.  This also implies there is a well-defined function $\phi:\pi_1(S^1)\to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by taking the winding number of a representative loop from a given homotopy class.
- The $\phi$ function is a homomorphism.  We already showed each homotopy class is represented by a function $e^{2\pi ikt}$ for some $k$.  The loop composition of $e^{2\pi ikt}$ and $e^{2\pi i\ell t}$ is a piecewise differentiable loop with winding number $k+\ell$, so $\phi$ is a homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}$ as an additive group.
- Every winding number is attainable since $e^{2\pi ikt}$ has winding number $k$.  Hence, $\phi$ is surjective.
- Injectivity was that every loop is homotopic to some $e^{2\pi ikt}$, which has zero winding number only if $k=0$, which would imply the original loop was nullhomotopic.
- Therefore $\phi:\pi_1(S^1)\to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism.

**Your questions**

1. 5.6 is that the homomorphism is an injection.  Since it is also a surjection, the homomorphism is an isomorphism.
2. For a subspace $A\subset X$ with inclusion map $i:A\to X$, a retraction $r:X\to A$ is a map such that $r\circ i=\operatorname{id}_A$.  That is, where $r(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$.  Since $\pi_1$ is a functor, the induced maps satisfy $r_*\circ i_*=\operatorname{id}_{\pi_1(A)}$, which means $r_*$ is surjective.  If $\pi_1(X)=1$, then by surjectivity $\pi_1(A)=1$.  This is why $\pi_1(A)$ cannot be nontrivial if $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial.
3. An infinite cyclic fundamental group means there is one thing you can go around.  If you try to define a function $X\to \mathbb{R}$ locally, there is no guarantee the local definitions will come together into a global definition; for example, the complex logarithm $\log:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\to \mathbb{C}+2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$ is only defined up to addition by integer multiples of $2\pi i$, which is sort of a consequence of $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}-\{0\})\cong \mathbb{Z}$.  If you've heard of branch cuts, that is where you cut $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ along a ray to trivialize its fundamental group.
4. For groups, all you need to check of a function to see it is a homomorphism is that $r_{a\cdot b}=r_a+r_b$ (that the composition in one group is carried to the composition of the next; if $\psi:G\to A$ is a function from a multiplicative group to an additive group, then if $\psi(gh)=\psi(g)+\psi(h)$ for all $g,h\in G$, the function is a homomorphism).  Here, $r:\pi_1(S^1)\to \mathbb{Z}$ is the function that 5.5 is describing to be a homomorphism.

Comment: What type of functor is $\pi_{1}$?